# How to fix number of females employees in a shift

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am adding a custom rule for Employee shift where i have 4 types of shifts and in one type of shift the number of female employees have to be fix

i have tried adding a field in shift class namely requiredFemalesEmployees which is set to 1
   //hard constraint
   rule "OneFemaleInShiftA"

```
when    
$gender:Employee(gender=="F")
 $rfe:Shift(requiredFemalesEmployees==1)
 accumulate(
$a:ShiftAssignment(employee==$gender,$shift:shift.requiredFemalesEmployees),
 $total :count($a)
)

then
 if($total.intValue()!=1){
 scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, - 1);
 }
```

end

any suggestions will be a great help.

Comment: how is this related to Java?

Comment: optaplanner is written in java and the rules dialect is also java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you created a variable named $rfe, but is unused, and in this line: 
$a:ShiftAssignment(employee==$gender,$shift:**shift.requiredFemalesEmployees**), what'r you assigning to $shift ?

This is my example:

```
rule "oneFemaleInShift"
    when    
        $gender:Employee(gender=="F")
        $rfe:Shift(requiredFemalesEmployees==1)
        Number(intValue!=1) from accumulate(
            $a:ShiftAssignment(employee==$gender, ¿¿$shift:shift.requiredFemalesEmployees??),
            count($a)
        )

    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, - 1);
```

We need the domain model or the source of java POJOs to know the relations between them.

I think this will help you:

```
rule "oneFemaleInShift"
    when    
        $femaleEmployee:Employee(gender=="F") //GET FEMALE POJOS
        $rfe:Shift(requiredFemalesEmployees==1) // GET SHIFT WHERE FEMALE IS REQUIRED
        Number(intValue > 0) from accumulate( //COUNT NUMBER OF FEMALE EMPLOYEES IN THAT SHIFT, PENALIZE SOLUTION WHERE THERE ARE LESS THAN 1
            $a:ShiftAssignment(employee==$femaleEmployee, shift==$rfe), 
            count($a)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, - 1); // LOOK AT THE VALUE OF HARD SCORE, PROPORTION WITH OTHER HARD CONSTRAINT
```

Comment: iam trying to edit the nurse rostering example to have gender constraint male and female and add one male and one female in a shift